# Ошибка при сериализации DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xml, сериализация

После нажатия на кнопку, должно содержимое DataGrid должно экспортироваться в XML при помощи сериализации, но происходит ошибка:

[image]

Код:

```
string filePath = @AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "students.xml";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<>));
var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
serializer.Serialize(writer, gridStudents.ItemsSource);
writer.Close();
```

Данные в DataGrid уже присутствуют.

Comment: почему у вас List<> - ничем не типизирован? И почему вообще сериалайзер это XmlSerializer(typeof(List<>))?

Answer (score 0):

У вас `List<>` - общий тип без параметра, поэтому сериализатор, во-первых, не знает как распарсить содержимое, а, во-вторых, не сможет создать экземпляр объекта.

Можно, например, создать класс, который будет соответствовать содержимому xml документа, и уже его передать в `new XmlSerializer()`;

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
```

Подробнее можно прочитать, например здесь: [Examples of XML Serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка System.InvalidOperationException: "Ошибка при создании документа XML."  InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Data.DataView" к типу "Carbide.Students".

Вот код класса:




    public class Students
    {
        public string Student;
    }

Comment: @R.Wilde тип, передаваемый в конструктор сериализатора должен соответствовать типу `ItemsSource`. Попробуйте
`var serializer = new XmlSerializer(gridStudents.ItemsSource.GetType());
var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
serializer.Serialize(writer, gridStudents.ItemsSource);
`